# Neither data annotations nor fluent API are mapping my sql column to my Id in my object

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I have the following class and DbContext. I've tried both data annotations and fluent api but both are somehow ignored and I get the exception listed below. What am I doing wrong?

my class

```
[Table("Users")]
public class EFUser : IUser<int>
{
    // [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    // [Column("EmployeeId")]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my DbContext.

```
public class XceleratorContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EFUser>()
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnName("EmployeeId")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EFUser> GetUser(int? employeeId = null, string userName = null, string passwordHash = null)
    {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<EFUser>(
            " exec dbo.GetUser @employeeId, @userName, @passwordHash ",
            GetSqlParameter("employeeId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, value: employeeId),
            GetSqlParameter("userName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, userName),
            GetSqlParameter("passwordHash", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, passwordHash));
    }

    private static SqlParameter GetSqlParameter<T>(string name, System.Data.SqlDbType type, int? size = null, T? value = null) where T : struct
    {
        var res = new SqlParameter(name, type) { Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value };

        if (size.HasValue)
            res.Size = size.Value;

        return res;
    }

    private static SqlParameter GetSqlParameter(string name, System.Data.SqlDbType type, int size, string value)
    {
        return new SqlParameter(name, type, size) { Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value };
    }
}
```

and finally the exception

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146232004
Message=The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EFUser'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
Source=EntityFramework
```

EDIT: It seems to be that if there is a base class (in this case an interface), the column mapping does not work. Is there a way around this or a fix?

EDIT2: I revoke my last statement. I removed the interface and the problem still exists.

EDIT3: It seems to be that the Column data annotation does not work with EntityFramework SqlQuery. I have the same problem as an older post here [EntityFramework SqlQuery does not work with custom mapping (DataAnnotation Column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733523/entityframework-sqlquery-does-not-work-with-custom-mapping-dataannotation-colum)

Comment: What's in IUser<int>?

Comment: @VirginiaMadsen it's the [IUser interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613291(v=vs.108).aspx) from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core